# Style Switching

Tags: css

Any tips or tricks on how to get a website to show a different stylesheet when you click on a menu item? What I want is one link to load a green css style and the other links keep the default style sheet. I am using U-Design.

Thanks in a advance!

Comment: are you talking about changing the style in the current page or load diferent pages with diferent styles?

Comment: Loading a different page with a different style. So when you click on Green it changes to a green style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), with those, you can check in which page you are, and load a diferent stylesheet for each option.

A little example using [`is_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

```
if(is_page('about')){

echo '<link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
} else {
echo '<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
}
```

That should go in your `header.php` file, or you could create diferent headers for diferent pages, and then use the [`get_header`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) function. There are other ways to deal with headers, but that's a diferent topic.